# Is there any built-in control (or maybe someone has coded one) to select an image from Google Images and put in an ImageView for Android?

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, android-image, google-image-search

The title speaks for itself really. I was wondering if there is some simple way (similar to opening the Photo Gallery) to select an image in Google Images and then passing it back to an ImageView for Android?

Has anyone done this?

Answer (score 0):

It's a fairly commong task within android. You can take a look to the following tutorial to accomplish exactly what you need.

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/pick-image-from-galary-android-app/

Good luck!